# Does spring allows hyphen in the path variables

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller

I am working on a project, and currently, the path looks like this: `order/{pathVariable1}/{pathVariable2}/path`
but this / has added extra complexity to the project and for different reasons we want to avoid / between path variables.
is it possible to have a path like the folllowing in Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "order/{pathVariable1}-{pathVariable2}/path", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getOrder(@PathVariable Integer pathVariable1, @PathVariable Integer pathVariable2){
...
}
```

if not, what do you suggest on this?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried it, but the code is too complex that I am not sure if its working or not. Also, I want to know if this kind of situations is really allowed or not, and if anybody has a better idea to avoid /

Comment: What's complex on creating simple controller with the method from your example? If it has to be, in newly generated spring boot project? You have tried it in 10 minutes...

Comment: Better idea would be to use standard path build up, i.e. {pathVariable1}/{pathVariable2}. In my opinon you do not win anything with the hyphen-based setup. As alternative you might have a look at matrix variables but that's  by far not what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: have just one pathvariable which will have '-' separated  vals, then split it inside your controller method.